# Customise co-first author and corresponding author in article- latex

Tags: footnotes

Are there any easy ways to set co-first author and corresponding author in the footnotes of an article? I do not want use Elsarticle template. Please advise.

The latex codes are attached as follows;

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}


\usepackage{authblk}
\renewcommand*{\Authsep}{, }
\renewcommand*{\Authand}{, }
\renewcommand*{\Authands}{, }
\renewcommand*{\Authfont}{\normalsize\normalfont}    
\renewcommand*{\Affilfont}{\normalsize\normalfont}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 

\title{\textbf{{\large Title}}}

\author[a,1]{XXX}
\author[a,\textasteriskcentered]{YYY}
\author[b,1]{ZZZ}

\affil[a]{\textit{AAA BBB CCC}}
\affil[b]{\textit{AAAaaa BBBaaa CCCaaa}}
\date{}    

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Some texts...\\
1 indicates co-first author, and should be accompanied by footnote: \\ \textsuperscript{1} Contribute to equally to this study. \\
\textasteriskcentered indicates corresponding author, and should be accompanied by footnote: \\ \textsuperscript{*} Corresponding author. Email: xxx@yyy.zzz.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why don't you just use `footnote`?

Comment: cannot work using footnote.